# MergeSort, problema de lógica

Tags: java, algoritmo, classificação

Senhores, estou tendo um problema com meu algoritmo de ordenação MergeSort, sinto que o problema está na lógica.

Código do Merge:

```
static void mergesort(int[] x,int inicio,int fim){
        if(inicio<fim){
            int meio;
            meio=((inicio+fim)/2);
            mergesort(x,inicio,meio);
            mergesort(x,meio+1,fim);
            intercala(x,inicio,fim,meio);
        }
    }
    static void intercala(int x[],int inicio,int fim,int meio){
        int inicio_vetor1,inicio_vetor2,poslivre,i;
        int[] aux = new int[10];
        inicio_vetor1 = inicio;
        inicio_vetor2 = meio+1;
        poslivre = inicio;
        while(inicio_vetor1<=meio && inicio_vetor2<=fim){
            if(x[inicio_vetor1]<=x[inicio_vetor2]){
                aux[poslivre]=x[inicio_vetor1];
                inicio_vetor1+=1;
            }
            else{
                aux[poslivre]=x[inicio_vetor2];
                inicio_vetor2++;
            }
            poslivre+=1;
        }
        for(i = inicio_vetor1;i<=meio;i++){
            aux[poslivre]=x[inicio_vetor1];
            poslivre+=1;
        }
        for(i = inicio_vetor2;i<=fim;i++){
            aux[poslivre]=x[inicio_vetor2];
            poslivre+=1;
        }
        for(i =inicio;i<=fim;i++){
            x[i]=aux[i];
        }
    }
```

Função `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] x = {6,2,1,3,0};
    mergesort(x,0,x.length-1);
    for(int y:x) System.out.println(y);
}
```

Saída:

```
0
1
2
2
3
```

Como podem ver, o algoritmo ordena, porém está engolindo números e não estou conseguindo achar o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há dois erros. O primeiro está aqui:

```
       int[] aux = new int[10];
```

Era para ser `new int[x.length]`!

Mas o seu grande erro está aqui:

```
        for(i = inicio_vetor1;i<=meio;i++){
            aux[poslivre]=x[inicio_vetor1];
            poslivre+=1;
        }
        for(i = inicio_vetor2;i<=fim;i++){
            aux[poslivre]=x[inicio_vetor2];
            poslivre+=1;
        }
```

Observe que você não está usando as variáveis `i` dentro dos laços! Deveria ser isso:

```
        for(i = inicio_vetor1;i<=meio;i++){
            aux[poslivre]=x[i];
            poslivre+=1;
        }
        for(i = inicio_vetor2;i<=fim;i++){
            aux[poslivre]=x[i];
            poslivre+=1;
        }
```

Com essas mudanças, ele funciona direitinho.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/WPAhng) - Também aproveitei e arrumei uns detalhes de formatação de código.

Comment: Simples e direto, obrigado.